# Using form input to choose a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cookies

I am still very much learning and probably this is relatively easy but I couldnt find what I wanted on the internet especially because I dont know exactly how to phrase my request!

I have a login page where people enter a "room" and some validation to check whether this room exists in the database. I currently have different tables in my database with content for every "room". I want to display the content of the table whose name was entered on the login page. Also I want that new info entered when logged into a room is stored in the database of that room.

I thought that the best way would be to store the room name in a cookie and call for that cookie every time you contact the database but I find it very hard to find good info on this functionality.

It probably is a lot to explain here but if someone knows a correct name that describes the functionality I am looking for, it would already help me out a lot!

Comment: this is a programming help site, yet i see no code in your question.

Comment: Make the user choose a room every time.  They won't necessarily choose the same one each time.

Comment: You should describe your table structure and what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  I tried to dissect your your question, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what you need.

Comment: I'll throw you a bone though. google "PHP Sessions." These are the easiest cookies to use.